# how to do one hot encoding in python for multiple categorical features together without getting trapped in dummy variable

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, classification

while doing one hot encoding we get trapped in dummy variable trap, to avoid this we drop one of those categorical features.

what if are doing OHE for multiple categorical features?

is there any intuitive way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe `pandas.get_dummies` can be helpful.

You can just do :

```
import pandas as pd
dummies = pd.get_dummies(X_data, columns=[col1, col2], drop_first=True)
```

Does that help you ? 
FInd the doc here : https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.get_dummies.html

Comment: Thanks, [@Mohamed AL ANI](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7171976/mohamed-al-ani)

Comment: No worries, if this is right, you can validate the answer so people who have the same issue as you can see it through